# Excel VBA: ActiveWorkbook not changing when I open a new Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

Here is the small bit of code that should play a role:

```
Workbooks.Open (MPPGLoc)

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MPPG").Activate

ActiveSheet.Move Before:=Workbooks("DPV Acq Test.xlsm").Sheets(1)
```

I am having the user input the file location for a payment plan, then supposedly going to the correct sheet in the plan and trying to copy it into a different workbook which automates everything. However this keeps simply moving one of the worksheets in the original workbook in front of the other worksheets.

Not sure if the problem is because opening a workbook doesn't necessarily make it active, or a problem with my move function. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And hence you should avoid using `Activeworkbook` Use Objects.

See this example (**Untested**)

```
Dim wb As worksbook, wbNew As Workbook
Dim wsNew As Worksheet

'~~> I am assuming that you are running the code from
'~~> Workbooks("DPV Acq Test.xlsm") 
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Set wbNew = Workbooks.Open(MPPGLoc)
Set wsNew = wbNew.Sheets("MPPG")

wsNew.Move Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. First time using multiple workbooks wasn't aware of the disadvantages with ActiveWorkbook. I'll keep this in mind in the future.

Comment: you should avoid using `Activeworkbook` because when you are working with several workbooks, sometime the active workbook is not the one you may think it is and hence you should always work with objects :) Hope your problem is solved